# Google Nearby Notifications

Tags: android, google-nearby

I have been working on nearby notifications, there are some points I would like to know

1. Is the nearby feature enabled by default in Android devices until the user disables it?
2. In which Android versions the nearby icon will be shown in Notification Settings bar?

Comment: Probably you need to elaborate. These explanations are very priliminary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearby Notifications is turned on when Bluetooth and High Accuracy location are both on and if you haven't explicity opted out in the Nearby section of Google Settings. You'll also need Wifi in most cases.

Nearby raises both Min and Low priority notifications. The Low priority notifications show the icon, while the Min priority ones don't. So, whether the icon shows or not is dependant on the suggestion rather than the Android version.